# usb port doesnt provide enough power for my mouse

Tags: usb, mouse

The happened about 2-3 days ago. The problem is that my mouse suddenly stopped working and it said that the device not recognized or something like that. I just bought a new one but this one isn't working either. Whenever I plug the mouse in the laser lights up for a sec and starts to light poorly.

Comment: If it was working properly and suddenly stopped, it is unlikely that it is a power problem. Please edit your question to add more info: OS, programs, anything you did just before it stopped.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I'd be wary of concluding that it s unlikely a power problem based on that..  It's normal with tech that things work then they don't.  And sometimes things look to the end user like it was perfect then suddenly stopped, but that's not really the case, just the end user or human often has a limited perspective and doesn't see the gradual deteroration of the thing at the electronic level or might not recognise the symptoms as indicative of a problem with that thing.

Answer (score 2):

Did you attempt to go into Device Manager and remove all USB ports, devices, reboot and let Windows reinstall the drivers?

USB Devices Not Working Properly:

1. Press Windows Key + R and type "devmgmt.msc" in the Run dialog box to open Device Manager

   [image: Run dialog box]
2. When the Device Manager window opens, seek the USB device you're having problems with. It could be listed under Human Interface Devices as USB Input Device or if you don't see it there, expand "Universal Serial Bus controllers" to find the USB you're having an issue with.To find the one from the list for which you have an issue, you have to follow the trial and error method. That is, plug and remove the device and note the changes among the list of devices for Universal Serial Bus controllers. The entry which is appeared and then removed subsequently is the entry for issued device. Keep the device plugged in and right click over this entry, pick Properties.

   [image: Device Manager]
3. In the device properties window shown below, switch to Details tab. Now click the drop-down menu for Property and select Device Instance Path. Note down the corresponding Value because we will need this value in further steps. By the way, this value is combination of three IDs; namely Vendor ID (VID), Product ID (PID), Instance ID.

   [image: properties]
4. Press Windows Key + R combination, type put "regedit" in Run dialog box and hit Enter to open the "Registry Editor".

   [image: properties]
5. Navigate here:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\<Device Instance Path>\Device Parameters
   ```

   [image: Device Parameters]

   Substitute the Device Instance Path part (after USB) obtained from the step 3.
6. In the right pane of Device Parameters key look for the "DWORD" named EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled which must be showing its Value data as 1. Double click on the same to get this:

   [image: DWORD]
7. In the above shown box, change the Value data to 0. Click OK. You may now close the Registry Editor as well as Device Manager.

Reboot the machine to get fixed!

Comment: That is a really inefficient way of communcating a point, like baby steps. Bear in mind this is superuser, you don't need to overdo the pictures. You can say `start..run`  or  orb..run, or  "bring up a run dialog box with window key +R" No need to go so far as to show a picture of it.  No technical person would want to have to scroll through that wtih all those pictures for what could've been said in 1-3 paragraphs.

Comment: It's just basic communication skills. Imagine if a book for programmers said "Move the mouse cursor up by moving the mouse upwards"  it'd end up enormous and people wouldn't buy it, that's why programming books don't do that. Similarly here.  And similarly, a reason why I have 15000 rep points (compared to your 39), is my communication skills. And I have almost never been called out for too little information, my posts are full of all necessarly information.  I do often call out others for too little information.

Comment: And there is a big difference between providing information and breaking things down into baby steps (which doesn't actually add any information). Furthermore, please show me where you think people have trolled you for providing too little information? (be interesting to see that, and if they had asked you for more informatoin, I would be surprised if they meant they wanted you to break things down into baby steps, but you're welcome to show me)

Comment: I can't see where they think you provided too little information and certainly they didn't ask you for baby steps.  A person criticised where you wrote ""Would anyone happen to know how to approach the issue of removing white space?"     They said it was too vague.  That's not a request for you to break down in baby steps what you mean.  It's just that the stackexchange creators don't like or cater to those kind of questions,unfortunately.The people that built the site aren't keen on answers that might be discussion based, or Qs that might get answers that are discussion-like.

Comment: So sometimes questions have to be framed such that they're not going to be labelled "subjective" by moderators. and that question you were criticised on at the link you provided, had the "subjective" issue. That's nothing to do with your answer here though.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is unlikely. The voltage supplied over USB would not change  and neither will the power requirements of your mouse. Most likely some circuitry inside is dying and it will need to be replaced.

There are a few things to check before calling the mouse dead:

- First, try the mouse on another computer, a friend's laptop, Chromebook, anything that supports a USB mouse. If you do that and it does *not* work, it's the mouse which will save you plenty of time figuring out what changed on your system.
- If the mouse is not dead, it could be the port. Try different ports on your computer. Preferably one that is connected right on the motherboard. If you are using a front-case-port, they could be defective or a cable got disconnected. If you are using a USB hub, remove it and try the mouse without it. In fact, as a sanity check, disconnect all other USB devices except for the keyboard. It is possible that there is interference or a new device attached is somehow lowering the voltage left for the mouse.
- You did not say what operating system you are using but since you know the time-frame you should be able to get the update history and see what happened around that day. Any driver or kernel update could be suspicious. Most operating systems allow you to remove an update or restoring a previous version so that you can reboot and try the mouse again.
- Before trying to remove updates, there is another way to check if the problem is related to the operating system. Some modern BIOS support mouse control, if yours does, try entering the BIOS (usually done by pressing DEL when booting) and see if your mouse responds. If it works, then you'll have to dig into the OS updates and newly installed drivers.
- If your BIOS does not support mouse control, you can still try with a bootable disk (CD/DVD/USB), doesn't matter which. Just insert media (Linux Live Disks are free and very common) and see if your mouse works normally (even the Windows Installation Disk might have mouse control). You don't need to fo through the installation, just advance one or two screens until there's a cursor you can control.

The strategy for solving such issues is to eliminate what is not wrong. If you get the mouse to work in the BIOS or Live CD, then it has to be something running in your operating system. If it does not work without booting into the OS, then you have a hardware problem.